# Match each keyword at least once

Tags: search, solr

I'm  trying to configure the scoring logic in Apache Solr 4.10.
I want to maximize the number of DISTINCT keywords matched.
In other words, each keyword should be matched at least once.
For example, this is what I'm currently seeing:

```
q=foo+bar+baz
```

Result:

```
doc1: foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
doc2: foo bar bar bar 
doc3: foo bar baz
```

This is not what I want. I want doc3 to appear at the top (since all keywords are matched), then doc2, then doc1. I tried setting mm=100% but then ONLY doc3 is returned and doc1 and doc2 are not displayed at all.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use  omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" in your field definition, you will get the result you want; the number of times a search term is matched in the document will not change the score; the score will then only be impacted by the number of different search terms that match the document.

Comment: I don't want the frequency to be omitted completely - I just want it to score drastically less than the total number of terms matched. Is there a way to boost number of distinct matches over frequency?

Comment: Then you could index your content in two separate fields, one with omitTermFreqAndPositions="true", one with omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" ; query against both fields and experiments with boosts (e.g. field1OmitTermFreq^2.3 field2IncludeTermFreq^1) - the effect will be that both the number of different matches, and the number of matches will contribute to the score. The relative boosts between the two fields can be tuned to suit your preference as to which is more important - some experimentation will be required.

Comment: That works. Thanks. Alternatively I was looking into overriding DefaultSimilarity class to boost the coord score. coord indicates how many unique keywords are hit